# Using a Switch Statement to change Values & Insert Labels for Text Inputs based on their preexisting values

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'd like to target a specific group of text inputs based on their preexisting values and replace their values and insert a label before them using a switch statement. The only problem I'm running into is targeting the individual input fields. I wasn't exactly sure what to put into the case portion for them so that the script would identify them and make the changes.

**HTML**

```
<input id="firstname" type="text" value="firstname"></input>
<input id="lastname" type="text" value="lastname"></input>
<input id="email" type="text" value="email"></input>
```

**Javascript**

```
var form = $('input[type="text"]');

switch (form) {
    case 
        $('form').attr('value', 'First Name').insertBefore('<label for=\"firstname\">First Name</label>');
    case 
        $('form').attr('value', 'Last Name').insertBefore('<label for=\"lastname\">Last Name</label>');
    case 
        $('form').attr('value', 'Email').insertBefore('<label for=\"email\">Email Address</label>');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is what you need: http://jqversion.com/#!/Rskx1fa/1

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
  switch($(this).attr('id')) {
    case 'firstname':
      $('<label for="firstname">First Name</label>').insertBefore($(this));
      $(this).val('First name');
      break;

    case 'lastname':
      $('<label for="lastname">Last Name</label>').insertBefore($(this));
      $(this).val('Last name');
      break;
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand why youre opting for a switch case. Seems to me youre better of using a loop and inserting a label using their value as such:(assuming youre using jquery)

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
$(this).insertBefore('<label for="'+ $(this).attr('name') + '">' + $(this).val() + '</label>');
});
```